# How to prevent Excel's Extend data range formats and formulas from changing formulas entered by code

Tags: excel, vba

After code execution ends, Excel expands ranges in formulas entered by the code to include the entire list and not the range that was entered. How can I prevent this?

When I check the formulas during code execution, the ranges appear correct. As soon as code execution ends, the ranges in all the formulas expand. I don't want to permanently disable the expand ranges function if I don't have to.

```
Application.ExtendList = False  
    oSht.Cells(oRow, 11).FormulaR1C1 = "=ROUND(100*SUMIF(R2C4:RC4,RC4,R2C8:RC8)/RC9,0)"  
Application.ExtendList = True
```

I want formulas in subsequent rows to look like this:

```
SUMIF($D$2:D845,D845,$H$2:H845)  
SUMIF($D$2:D846,D846,$H$2:H846)  
SUMIF($D$2:D847,D847,$H$2:H847)  
SUMIF($D$2:D848,D848,$H$2:H848)
```

Excel changes the formula to look like this:

```
SUMIF($D$2:D848,D845,$H$2:H848)  
SUMIF($D$2:D848,D846,$H$2:H848)  
SUMIF($D$2:D848,D847,$H$2:H848)  
SUMIF($D$2:D848,D848,$H$2:H848)
```

Comment: Show more of your code... your loop would be kind of important for this,  Common problem is nesting a loop and this is the last in the nested loop before moving to next oRow.

Answer (score 0):

This code will insert the formula to the entire range, updating non-fixed references relative to placement (e.g., if it doesn't have "$", it will be updated as you move between rows or columns), which does not require a loop:

```
with sheets("")
    .range(.cells(startRow,startCol),.cells(endRow,endCol)).formula = "=SUMIF($D$2:D845,D845,$H$2:H845)"
End with
```

---

If you want to loop, you need your code to update the formula respective to the loop such that... note that it puts the exact formula in the cell:

```
with sheets("")
    .cells(oRow,11).formula = "=SUMIF($D$2:D" & oRow-1 & ",D" & oRow & ",$H$2:H" & oRow-1 & ")"
End with
```

Comment: I ran my code with a break at the next step after the loop that creates all the formulas. The formulas are correct at that point.  The next line is:       
    Application.ExtendList = False  The formulas are still correct after executing that line. They only change to the incorrect range after code execution is complete.

Comment: @SeanM take out the extendlist completely and check that it executes as intended.  I'm sitll getting hungup on your R1C1 notation, e.g., R12C2 = B2 no matter the row i input my formula to, but R[0]C2 will input utilize the row I'm working on and the second column (B#).